# Variables in .htaccess Redirect

Tags: string, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been looking for a while, but I can't quite work this out...so here goes...i've edited my urls so that when I have a URL such as:

http://example.co.uk/Review.php?type=anime&type2=tv&id=109&title=shingekinobahamutgenesis

It becomes:

http://example.co.uk/anime/tv/109/shingekinobahamutgenesis/

using .htaccess. This bit has gone well and the new URL works, however the old URL doesn't redirect to this URL and works as well. This causes problems when people use our mobile site links as it redirects them to the old unchanged URL.

our .htaccess code is like so:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*?)(%20)([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule    ^adminarea/?$ /adminarea.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^calendar/?$ /calendar.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^searching/?$    /searching.php    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /admin/$1.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /search.php?type=$1    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /search.php?type=$1&im=$2&name=$3    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /search.php?type=$1&genre=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/list/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /search.php?type=$1&letter=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^extra/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /rrww12o.php?type=$1&id=$2&genre1=$3&title=$4    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /Review.php?type=$1&type2=$2&id=$3&title=$4    [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
CheckSpelling on

RewriteBase /

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|windows\ phone|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

    # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
    # Now redirect to the mobile site
    RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I've tried multiple versions of [R=301] and [R] redirects, but if I just add it to the end where I have [NC,QSA,L], it redirects the rewritten link to the original link (wrong way of course).

The reason for the $1 required, is that this isn't a static URL, as this covers multiple links to different MySQL records, as the records are always increasing, this must remain automatic like now.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

*Update: Does not work for OP*

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*?)(%20)([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [L,R=301,NE]

# Rerwite to Review.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /Review.php?type=$1&type2=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [NC,QSA,END]

# Redirect old url to new url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=([a-z0-9-]+)&type2=([a-z0-9-]+)&id=([a-z0-9-]+)&title=([a-z0-9-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Review\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/%4 [QSD,R,L]
```

Note the `END` flag on the `Review.php` rule - this prevents an infinite loop.

So, if you request `Review.php?type=anime&type2=tv&id=109&title=shingekinobahamutgenesis`, you'll be redirected to `anime/tv/109/shingekinobahamutgenesis`, which will then be rewritten.

Comment: seems to kill the site when I do that...getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Might be the other string queries...I'll edit the code to show all the string queries.

Comment: Your code is throwing an Internal Server Error anyway - without my new condition and rule...

Comment: removing that didn't work for me.
Here is the original site link: http://anihelp.co.uk (the original htaccess definitely works).

Comment: I put `QSD` so that the original query string does not get appended onto the URL.

Comment: both QSD and END seems to crash the site.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why that is happening... Worked on my installation. You're more than likely running an older version of Apache.